# How to use the embedded Flash on Android?

Tags: android, flash

I know that Flash has been abandoned on the Android platform. But for a special reason, I still need to use Flash (SWF file) on an application that is used internally. So, now is there a way to make my application play Flash(has ActionScript) without installing other APK?

The minimum version of the target device is Android 4.4 (API 19)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to download swf during run time or can you embed it with your app?

Comment: @3vilguy I need to download and play it in run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was investigating same thing recently. Adobe AIR seems to be able to do it so I was pretty sure it's possible. After quite a lot of googling I found some useful info and proof of concept on some Chinese website (unfortunately it's already down :( ).
Fortunately they also linked a Github repository with that example. I was able to fork it and add some instructions about which files do you need to update if you want to use latest AIR SDK or see flash traces.
So there you go. You can use SWF file in your Android app (on new Intent) through AIR-runtime, without installing other APK:

[android-invoke-adobe-AIR](https://github.com/3vilguy/android-invoke-adobe-AIR)

There's one problem tho. You can pass some parameters from Java to AS3, but I couldn't find easy way for communicating between them later on. In AIR you could do that via ANE's and I was trying to extract some APKs to see how it works, but no luck. I did end up using socket communication (it's on `feature/SocketConnection` branch).

Hope you find it usefull.